# Why do gdal_translate and python gdal give wrong result (output spatial location) for translation of netcdf4 to geotiff?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, netcdf, gdal-translate

I try to convert netcdf4 file to raster by using gdal and python.
The netcdf4 file is in the WGS84 geographic coordinate system.
When I use "Make NetCDF Raster Layer" in ArcMap, the netcdf file is converted to raster and placed on the right spatial location.

However,when I use the commandline gdal_translate as below, the translated raster is placed on the wrong spatial location.

`'gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" NETCDF:"precip.nc4":precipitationCal "RasterPrecip.tiff"'`

I get same result for gdal python as shown below also. The converted raster is placed on wrong spatial location

`from osgeo import gdal
filename = "precip.nc4"
data = gdal.Open('NETCDF:"'+filename+'":precipitationCal')
Dataset = driver.Create(Newfile, xsize, ysize)
Dataset.SetGeoTransform(geo_transform)
Dataset.SetProjection(spatialRefProj)
Dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(rain)`

I am unable to get the projection from the file.
`data.GetProjection()` gives invalid (' ') projection.
As the file coordiante system is as WGS84, I used.

`spatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
spatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4326)`

Further, data.GetGeoTransform() gives
(57.4, 0.1, 0.0, 14.8, 0.0, -0.1).
The first value should be top lext, x (longitude). Here comes latitude value(57.4). I expected to get (6.4,0.1,0,62.0,0,-0.1). However, if I set this as geotransform, I still get wrong result.

I think that wrong geotransform which is read from the netcdf file may be the reason for wrong result but how is ArcMap reading correctly?

Additional information:
By commandline `gdalinfo NETCDF:"precip.nc4":precipitationCal` gives

`Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files:C:\precip.nc4
Size is 46, 84
Coordinate System is ''
Origin = (57.400000762939456,14.800000001149005)
Pixel Size = (0.100000000000000,-0.100000002298010)
Geolocation:
  LINE_OFFSET=0
  LINE_STEP=1
  PIXEL_OFFSET=0
  PIXEL_STEP=1
  SRS=GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
  X_BAND=1
  X_DATASET=NETCDF:"C:\precip.nc4":lon
  Y_BAND=1
  Y_DATASET=NETCDF:"C:\precip.nc4":lat
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  57.4000008,  14.8000000)
Lower Left  (  57.4000008,   6.3999998)
Upper Right (  62.0000008,  14.8000000)
Lower Right (  62.0000008,   6.3999998)
Center      (  59.7000008,  10.5999999)`